# Alpinejs x-on:click not working, attaching it to a parent div item

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

**I cannot get the console log after clicking on this element.However changing div to button will fetch result.
Here is my code snippet.**

```html
    <div class="navbar">
      <div x-on:click="console.log('clicked')" class="navitem msn">
        <div>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            class="h-6 w-6"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke="currentColor"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              stroke-width="2"
              d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"
            />
          </svg>
          <div class="navtitle">Title1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

You have a couple of errors:

- No `x-data` directive. You need at least an empty `x-data` on any Alpine.js component.
- There's a random "enter code here" string in the SVG code.
- You have a missing `</div>` element.

The corrected example:

```
<div x-data="" class="navbar">
  <div x-on:click="console.log('clicked')" class="navitem msn">
    <div>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        class="h-6 w-6"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="currentColor"
      >
        <path
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2"
          d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"
        />
      </svg>
      <div class="navtitle">Title1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "You need at least an empty x-data on any Alpine.js component" – I don't think this is mentioned as explicitly in the docs. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: What about data-less Alpine, i.e. https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/state#data-less-alpine? It looks like according to those docs you can have a simple `x-data` - without even a `=""`

Answer (score 3):

You need an empty x-data in any parent HTML tag, this should be enough.
They should've mentioned that on the docs tough.

Comment: Yup still is the same case. Then should have mentioned it though. 
I thought x-data needed only when depended on some value.
But no a simple alert() also needs a x-data attribute either on itself or parent element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also confused as to why it's not working.
Until I saw this post and saw this:

> Everything in Alpine starts with the x-data directive.

( from: https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data)

So instead of:

```
<div>
<button x-on:click="console.log('clicked')">...</button>
</div>
```

We need:

```
<div x-data>
<button x-on:click="console.log('clicked')">...</button>
</div>
```

To make it work!